# HTML.BeginForm not Routing to Controller Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an MVC website in C# with razor syntax.

I have some code here:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSignUp", "SignUpController", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    <input type="text" width="3000" value="" name="Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /
}
```

So this form should post to the SignUpController on the DoSignUp method. Instead of doing that it just posts back to the page I'm currently on which is called SignUp. I suspected there might be something wrong with my routing but when I look at the html that is being generated through the browser developer tools i see this:

```
<form action="" method="post">        
    <input type="text" width="3000" value="" name="selectedURL">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Edit: Well I wrote this out and then looked at my code again. The problem which I keep bloody doing is that SignUpController should just be SignUp.

Comment: Use `SignUp` , not `SignUpController`. `@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSignUp", "SignUp", FormMethod.Post))`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 'Controller' from your controller name (`SignUp`, not `SignUpController`). It's assumed to be a controller by convention

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSignUp", "SignUp", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    <input type="text" width="3000" value="" name="Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /
}
```